# ¿Cómo lograr que mi footer tenga los bordes redondos y un margen?

Tags: html, css, footer

Estoy intentando hacer un footer en HTML y CSS. Ese footer debe permanecer en la parte inferior de la pantalla, pero también debe tener un margen y los bordes redondos. He logrado la primera parte sin problemas, pero soy incapaz de lograr lo segundo.

Sé que el tema de los footers es un tema muy común en este foro y en todo internet, pero he sido incapaz de encontrar nada relacionado a conseguir que tenga los bordes redondos, y a tener un margen.

Esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```css
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Este es mi footer</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Es decir, debería verse un poco de fondo blanco en los lados del footer, y los bordes redondos (algo que no soy capaz de hacer).

Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda, llevo un buen rato probando cosas y buscando y no encontré nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-radius` es para darle bordes redondos, vas ajustando el valor segun quieras.
Pueden ser todas las esquinas, o puedes definir que esquinas cambiar.

No entiendo donde y como quieres el margen eso si.
Pero le acabo de agregar un `margin` a ver si eso es lo que buscas.

```css
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Este es mi footer</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Vale, infinitas gracias. Supongo que me compliqué la vida innecesariamente. Tu solución funciona perfectamente y es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Gracias. ^^

Comment: ahh uhh ehh nice !!! jaja, es algo muy simple la verdad, y no entendi del todo la petición, por eso me parecia raro que no encontrases `margin` o `border-radius`

Comment: Créeme que lo intenté todo jaja, infinidad de gracias. A veces, lo más sencillo es lo más eficaz jaja.